# FMAX Analysis through Time Quest Analyzer

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus

I'm new in VHDL and this is my first post on StackOverFlow. I've write this code in VHDL. Everythings works good except TimingQuest Analyzer. I don't know why but if I try to use the TimingQuest Analyzer for the entity "register8_bit" that return me "no paths report", btw if I use TimingQuest Analyzer for the entity "FLIP_FLOP_D" everythings goes well. If this question is inappropriate or too long I'll provide to delete.

```
----------------REGISTER A 8 BIT------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
---------------------------------------------------
entity register8_bit is
    port (din:                      in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            c, reset, en:           in std_logic;
            dout:                       out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end register8_bit;

architecture datablow of register8_bit is
---------AGGIUNGO I SEGUENTI COMPONENTS-----------
component FLIP_FLOP_D is
    port (
    e,r,i,c :in std_logic;
    o         :out std_logic );
end component;

begin
    RO  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(0),c,dout(0));
    R1  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(1),c,dout(1));
    R2  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(2),c,dout(2));
    R3  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(3),c,dout(3));
    R4  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(4),c,dout(4));
    R5  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(5),c,dout(5));
    R6  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(6),c,dout(6));
    R7  : FLIP_FLOP_D       port map (en,reset,din(7),c,dout(7));
end datablow;



entity FLIP_FLOP_D is port (
    e,r,i,c :in std_logic;
    o         :out std_logic );

end FLIP_FLOP_D;

architecture datablow of FLIP_FLOP_D is 

begin   
    process(e,r,c)
        begin
            if (r = '0') then
                o <= '0';
            elsif (rising_edge(c)) then
                if (e = '1') then
                    o <= i;
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;
end datablow;
```

Comment: You might like to follow [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61835418/fmax-analysis-through-timing-quest-tool-of-quartus-ll-vhdl). However, it is not answered yet.

Comment: Identically to the [commented duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61835418/fmax-analysis-through-timing-quest-tool-of-quartus-ll-vhdl) this question is about a tool not commonly used by programmers. The TimeQuest Timing Analyzer is used to determine static time of synthesized hardware produced from (here) a VHDL design specification.

Answer (score 0):

**First: what does Quartus TimeQuest II do?**

It evaluates the transit time of signal(s) through combinatorial path(s) between clocked design elements and checks if this combinatorial path is fast enough to allow the signal(s) to arrive at the destination clocked design element long enough before the receiving clock edge.

This "long enough" time is called *slack*.

If slack is negative, these signals arrive too late and your design is unlikely to function as intended. If it is positive, slack shows how much time the receiving design element will have to capture the signal, or, in other words, how much margin you might have to drive the whole design with a faster clock.

**Second: what do I need to allow TimeQuest II to do its work?**

Basically, everything that's mentioned above: (a) a design with "sending" and "receiving" clocked elements and (b) the clock rate of the clock feeding these elements.

For (a), you'll need a "Synopsys Design Constraints" (or .sdc) file, that at least needs to inform Quartus Time Quest II about the (external) clock's speed that drives your design. Without that, it cannot show reasonable results. Your .sdc file needs to have at least one line that defines that clock:

```
create_clock -period <clock period> -name <clock name> [get_ports {<clock port>}]
```

For (b), your design needs to provide at least the elements described above: a clocked "sending" element and a clocked "receiving" element with a combinatorial path in between.

It's usually not enough to just have that in your design HDL, it's also important that all of this is still existing after synthesis. Quartus synthesis will optimize away all elements of your design it determines unused.
To be sure all this is there, you should consult the RTL viewer.